# Write VSCode runner v0.1.0 for 2.0.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

This is the `runner` to run code directly inside VS Code but written for `v0.1.0` and I couldn't find the equivalent for version `v2.0.0`.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "python",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["${file}"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VS Code docs provides instructions for this here: [Migrating to Tasks 2.0.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_migrating-to-tasks-200).

> Here is a migration guide:
>
> - **taskName**: Use the label property instead.
> - **isShellCommand**: Use the `"type": "shell"` property instead.
> - ...
> - **showOutput**: Use the `"presentation" : { "reveal": "..." }` property instead.
> - ...

The `args` and `command` is unchanged. Also, instead of a single-level structure, you should now create a `tasks: []` array and you have separate configurations per `task`.

Your v0.1.0 tasks.json configuration migrated to v2.0.0 is now:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "run-my-python-script",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python",
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
}
```

where `"label"` can be anything, just to identify the task:

[image]

All the other configurations are discussed in the VS Code docs for [Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.